# Hibernate Connection Issue in Tomcat Server in Linux OS

Tags: java, mysql, linux, hibernate, tomcat

Hi I am using the Linux OS with Fedora release 17, My Hibernate configuration file is as follows

```
<hibernate-configuration>


   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>

<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="format_sql">false</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">40</property>  

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods">3000</property>     
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>

</hibernate-configuration>


   </session-factory>
```

With this configuration in Server I am getting the following error frequently

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]] with root cause
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatisticsImplementor(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1468)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatistics(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1464)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:346)
```

My Connection code is as follows,

```
public class DBConnection{

    private static  SessionFactory factory; 

    private static DBConnection singleton = new DBConnection();

    // private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private DBConnection(){ }

    /* Static 'instance' method */
    public static DBConnection getInstance( ) {
       return singleton;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){

         if (factory == null ) {

             try {
                 factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

               } catch (Throwable ex) {
                 System.err.println("Failed to create   sessionFactory object." + ex);
                 throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
             }
         }
         return factory;

     }


    public static Session getSession() 
    {
           return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }



   // Call this during shutdown
  public static void close() {
        factory.close();
        factory=null;


   }
```

Due to this My application gets slow down and I can see Sleep Queries in MySQL.

How to fix this? How can I configure in this environment? Any Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Session object is not thread safe in Hibernate. Are you using the same session across multiple threads, unless you synchronize the session objects

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan Thanks for your reply- I am using  same session across multiple threads in application. How to do in this environmemt?

Comment: May i ask you why are you doing it?

Comment: In my application I am using separate session creation for each request from the web application and I am closing it after each request in that function itself,  Session session = null;
        try
        {
            session = new DBConnection().getSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();tx.commit();
        session.close();
        DBConnection.close();


    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        DBConnection.close();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    please find the code above. I wil give u extra info if u need